# TransactionRequiredException even though transaction attribute is declared

Tags: transactions, ejb-3.1, jboss-eap-6

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.x.

I have `ejb.method1()` which is annotated with transaction attribute `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

from inside `ejb.method2()` which is annotated with transaction attribute `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)`

I am calling `ejb.method2()` from `ejb.method1()`

something like below

```
    ejb.method() {
        //some operation 
         ejb.method2();
        //some operation
    }

    ejb2.method2() {

        //some operation 

        merge(entity1); // no error here

        try {
           sendMessageToMQ // no error here} catch(Exception e) {
           entity.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        } catch() {Expcetion) {
           entity1.setStatus("ERROR");
        } finally {
           merge(entity1); // Throwing Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context
        }
    }
```

The code works if the execution completed within a minute, however it fails with below exception when it takes around 3 minutes. Transaction timeout is set to 15 minutes.

`Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: JBAS011469: Transaction is required to perform this operation (either use a transaction or extended persistence context`

Comment: seems like after the first merge() the transaction for some reasons has ended. Is merge() the method of the entityManager or your method?

Comment: Good catch.. Merge is our framework method which internally create certain versioned records and history records based on certain logic and perform insert and update using entity manager's merge. I will try to move the 2nd merge in a new method with transaction attribute and will update here.

Comment: Or may be the first merge is not at all required.

Comment: I would just pay attention to be in a single transaction and avoid merge to open a new transaction. Seems like in merge a commit happens so the transaction is closed when the flow comes in the final block. What is the scope of the merge method? You want to save the status in DB if sendMessageToMQ() was ok? Please update the question with the relevant code. Another thing that needs attention is the call of the merge in the final block.

Comment: Isn't it a good idea to have something in finally !

Comment: Guess you meant to put "?"  in the end of the phrase and not "!". Anyway going to your question, is not a good idea only in case merge() do some complicated logic and "plays" with the transactions. To be more precise, you need to handle the situation if something will go wrong inside the merge(). As it is the code, assuming that your merge() can throw any unchecked exception, the transaction will rollback. Is this something you want? For this I asked, share the relevant code.

Comment: The exception occurred during merging..  The access to a database, query persist/update, must have a transaction. you might add the transaction annotation to the method or you might use an extended EntityManager scope.

Comment: In general the annotation for the private methods does not have an effect.
These methods are not called under control of the container, therefore no new Tx is started.This is according to the EJB specification.
All methods called by a direct reference, no matter whether it is private or not, are not under container control and there are no annotations or other checks processed.  By default the Tx attribute is "Required", but in any case the behaviour will be different to what you expect. Take a look to your implementation and correct these..

Comment: After removing merge from finally and moved out of method2() and annotated it with transaction attribute - worked

Answer (score 0):

After extracting second merge method in a new method and annotating it with Transaction Attribute it worked for me. The method calling extracted method ha been annotated with Transaction Attribute Supports.

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
ejb.method() {
    //some operation 
     ejb.method2();
    //some operation
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
ejb2.method2() {
    //some operation 
    merge(entity1); // no error here
    try {
       sendMessageToMQ // no error here} catch(Exception e) {
       entity.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    } catch() {Expcetion) {
       entity1.setStatus("ERROR");
    } 
    thisService.updateMessageStatus(entity1);
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void updateMessageStatus(Entity entity) {
    merge(entity)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the solution is to enclose your `merge()` method inside a **new transaction**, example:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) 
public void updateMessageStatus(Entity entity) {
     merge(entity);
}
```

And everywhere call `updateMessageStatus()` and not directly `merge()`.

**Why your code is working?**

`@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)` on `updateMessageStatus()` is saying "In case the caller do NOT have any transaction then create a new one". 
As I wrote in the comments your first transaction ends after the first call to the merge. After this line:

```
merge(entity1); // no error here
```

When you call `updateMessageStatus()` it works since `REQUIRED` opens a new transaction and commits/rollback when `updateMessageStatus()` ends. 
You are just opening a new transaction since you do not have any active one in the second call. This is why my advice is to annotate `updateMessageStatus()` as `REQUIRES_NEW`

Another observation is regarding `SUPPORTS` (assuming you are calling `ejb2.method2()` inside `ejb.method()`)

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
ejb.method() {
     ejb2.method2();
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
ejb2.method2() {
    thisService.updateMessageStatus(entity1);
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public void updateMessageStatus(Entity entity) {

}
```

`@TransactionAttribute(SUPPORTS)` does not make sense if the method will be called only from `ejb2.method2()`, since `ejb.method()` will already have a transaction. I would let the default one `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRED)`